# Unicode Private Use Characters in NTFS Filenames

Tags: windows, unicode, filenames, ntfs

Windows uses characters in the Unicode private use area 0xf000 to 0xf0ff as a way of encoding characters that are legal in Linux filenames but not in Windows. These can come from Windows Subsystem for Linux, or from copying/creating files from various sources if you use network tools and/or external disks on different operating systems (e.g. FAT32 disks that have been used with MacOSX). The problem when you want to access these files from both WSL and Windows (e.g. using python) is that you need to know what the mapping is and I can't find a definitive table. A bit of experimentation from WSL suggests that the mapping from WSL to Windows is as follows:

```
< U+f03c
> U+f03e
: U+f03a
" U+f022
\ U+f05c
| U+f07c
? U+f03f
* U+f02a
```

but snooping through my Windows files has found quite a few more code points in this range and I can't find out what they map to. My best guess so far (based on context) is

```
U+f009 - tab
U+f00a - linefeed
U+f00d - carriage return
U+f020 - double quote
U+f021 - vertical line
U+f022 - colon or solidus
U+f023 - less than sign
U+f024 - greater than sign
U+f025 - question mark
U+f026 - reverse solidus
U+f027 - vertical line
U+f028 - space [at end of filename]
U+f029 - full stop [at end of filename]
```

My guess is that deep within the Microsoft documentation there is a list of the mappings (or at least the recommended mappings). Or maybe various people making cross platform tools have come up with their own mappings over time. I am hoping that someone can point me to some sources of this information.

Once I a have a better idea about what mapping I should use, my plan is to write a python program that unifies all of these (or at least identifies the files so I can work out what to do). I shall probably just rename all the files so that these characters are all mapped to their fullwidth equivalent since that will be recognisable (but ugly) on all my file systems. The code I have so far is this:

```py
map_dict = {
    0xf009:'\uff3ct', # tab
    0xf00a:'\uff3cn', # linefeed
    0xf00d:'\uff3cr', # carriage return
    0xf020:'\uff02', # double quote
    0xf021:'\uff5c', # vertical line
    0xf022:'\uff1a', # colon or solidus
    0xf023:'\uff1c', # less than sign
    0xf024:'\uff1e', # more than sign
    0xf025:'\uff1f', # question mark
    0xf026:'\uff3c', # reverse solidus
    0xf027:'\uff5c', # vertical line
    0xf028:' ', # this seems to be at the end of the filename
    0xf029:'.', # this seems to be at the end of the filename
    0xf03a:'\uff1a', # colon
    0xf03f:'\uff1f', # question mark
    0xf8ff:'Apple\u2122', # Apple trade mark
    }

def map_filename(input_name, map_dict):
    output_name = ""
    mapped = False
    for c in str(input_name):
        code_point = ord(c)
        if code_point in map_dict:
            output_name += map_dict[code_point]
            mapped = True
        else:
            if ((code_point >= 0xe000 and code_point <= 0xf8ff)
            or (code_point >= 0xf0000 and code_point <= 0xfffff)
            or (code_point >= 0x100000 and code_point <= 0x10ffff)):
                print('Error "%s" contains unmapped private use character %04x' % (input_name, code_point))
                sys.exit(1)
            output_name += c
    return (output_name, mapped)
```

However this is entirely guesswork and has a lot of gaps. There must be lists of how WSL maps all the unusual characters, and equally how MacOS or Linux encode their non-Windows characters in FAT32 disks and elsewhere.

Comment: [1] Your post is very detailed, but you haven't linked to any information sources, and you haven't actually asked a specific question. Can you update your question accordingly? [2] If you are just seeking a link to some Microsoft documentation on private area mappings then your question is arguably off topic here, and probably belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead. [3] [This superuser answer](https://serverfault.com/a/73184) which mentions how Windows handles u+f022 in filenames may be of interest.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-specialchars